# Flutter Scroll flexibleSpaceBar content under the sliverAppBar content

Tags: flutter, dart, sliverappbar

I'm looking to display some features in this area

[image]

and when the user scroll up to the top, oclude it by the top bar.
The issue is that its being overlapped
[image]

The app bar consist of a sliverAppBar widget and following multiple setups I've not managed to occlude the flexible space. Here is the code:

```
SliverAppBar(
          primary: true,
          floating: true,
          collapsedHeight: 80,
          toolbarHeight: 80,
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: 320,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: Text("leading"),
          title: Text("tghe title"),
          actions: [Text("some actions!")],
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar.createSettings(
            minExtent: 0,
            maxExtent: 230,
            toolbarOpacity: 1,
            currentExtent: 0,
            child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              
              collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
              stretchModes: [StretchMode.zoomBackground],
              title: Text("settings"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Can you include your desire UI on collapsed case?

Comment: The desired collapsed is to only show the content from the top and hide all the flexiblespacebar content

Comment: Does `SliverAppBar.large` fill your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the property
titlePadding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 20, top: 80)
works as a workaround since the extra padding makes the flexibleSpaceBar content to be occluded by the title,leading and actions widgets when scrolled up.
[image]